# Errno::EEXIST error during image upload using CKEditor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor, ubuntu-14.04, capistrano3

I am getting this error while I try to upload file in CKEditor from my rails 3.2 app.

I have used capistrano for deployment and its stuck at this error now.

It works in my local and UAT environment but not in production environment.

Previously I had access denied issues I fixed that and now I get the below error:

```
An Errno::EEXIST occurred in pictures#create_pic:

  File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /var/www/web_cc_cap1/releases/20161230073928/public/system
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:247:in `mkdir'
```

#### deploy.rb

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.6.1'

set :application, 'web_app'
set :repo_url, 'sample.git'

# set :rvm_ruby_string, "2.1.0@capistrano"
# set :rvm_ruby_version, "2.1.0"
# set :rvm_type, :system

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp
# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name

set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system')
set :log_level, :debug

# set :nginx_roles, :web
# default_run_options[:pty] = true
set :pty, true

set :resque_verbose, false
```

Complete backtrace which I got from the error notification mail:

```
-------------------------------
Backtrace:
-------------------------------

  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:247:in `mkdir'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:247:in `fu_mkdir'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:224:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:222:in `reverse_each'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:222:in `block in mkdir_p'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:208:in `each'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:208:in `mkdir_p'
  carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:290:in `mkdir!'
  carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:209:in `copy_to'
  carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/storage/file.rb:34:in `store!'
  carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/store.rb:59:in `block in store!'
  carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:17:in `with_callbacks'
  carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/store.rb:58:in `store!'
  carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:371:in `store!'
  carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:223:in `store_data!'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:427:in `_run__1373012483211490398__save__252829260382173436__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_save_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `create_or_update'
  activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:84:in `save'
  activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save'
  activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
  activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block (2 levels) in save'
  activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
  activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
  activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block in save'
  activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
  activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:258:in `save'
  active_scaffold (3.3.3) lib/active_scaffold/extensions/unsaved_record.rb:15:in `save_with_unsaved_flag'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:707:in `respond_with_asset'
  app/controllers/pictures_controller.rb:17:in `create_pic'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:557:in `_run__1719685529573174046__process_action__303294515139870162__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:608:in `call'
  exception_notification (4.0.1) lib/exception_notification/rack.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/deflater.rb:13:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__904569922375962105__call__252829260382173436__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:102:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.14) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.14) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.14) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
  rack-ssl (1.3.3) lib/rack/ssl.rb:27:in `call'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:143:in `pass'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:155:in `invalidate'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:71:in `call!'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  railties (3.2.14) lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
  railties (3.2.14) lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
  railties (3.2.14) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.10/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:94:in `process_request'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.10/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:157:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.10/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:110:in `main_loop'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.10/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:414:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.10/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:111:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'
```

#### pictures_controller.rb

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json
  layout 'ckeditor/application'
  before_filter :login_required
  before_filter :find_asset, :only => [:destroy]
  before_filter :ckeditor_authorize!  
  before_filter :authorize_resource

  def create_pic
    @picture = Ckeditor.picture_model.new
      respond_with_asset(@picture)
  end
end
```

#### application_controller.rb

```
  def respond_with_asset(asset)

      file = params[:CKEditor].blank? ? params[:qqfile] : params[:upload]
      asset.data = Ckeditor::Http.normalize_param(file, request)
      callback = ckeditor_before_create_asset(asset)

      if callback && asset.save
        body = params[:CKEditor].blank? ? asset.to_json(:only=>[:id, :type]) : %Q"<script type='text/javascript'>
          window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(#{params[:CKEditorFuncNum]}, '#{config.relative_url_root}#{Ckeditor::Utils.escape_single_quotes(asset.url_content)}');
        </script>"

        render :text => body
      else
        render :nothing => true
      end
  end
```

#### Update: The S3 Mounting recipe that I have written

```
desc "Mounting S3 for the first time"
    task :mounting_s3 do
        on main_server, in: :sequence, wait: 5 do |host|
            as 'www-data' do
                within "#{code_folder_path}/current" do
                    code_folder = "#{code_folder_path}/current"
                    path = "#{code_folder_path}/current/public/system"
                    unmount_path = "#{code_folder_path}/shared/public/system"

                    # check first if public/system exists
                    puts "** Checking if public/system folder exists on #{host}"
                    puts "** testing if it is there #{test("[ -d #{path} ]")}"
                    if test("[ -d #{path} ]")
                        puts "** public/system folder exists.."
                        puts "** Checking if S3 is mounted"
                        result = capture "cd #{code_folder} && mountpoint public/system" , raise_on_non_zero_exit: false
                        puts "result #{result}"
                        if  result.match('is a mountpoint') != nil
                            puts "** S3 is mounted at #{path} on #{host}"
                        elsif result.match('is not a mountpoint') != nil
                            puts "** #{path} is not a mountpoint on #{host}"
                            execute! "cd #{code_folder} && sudo su - www-data -s /bin/bash -c 's3fs cc-s-p #{path}'"
                        end 
                    else
                        puts "** public/system folder does not exists.."
                        puts "** Mounting S3"
                        execute! "cd #{code_folder} && sudo su - www-data -s /bin/bash -c 's3fs cc-s-p #{path}'"
                    end 
                end
            end
        end 
    end

end
```

How can I fix this and what does this error mean?

Comment: Unless you expect an answer from a fortuneteller, please share the full stacktrace and _your_ code leading to this error. BTW, this error means you are trying to create a directory without having sufficient rights.

Comment: @mudasobwa I have added the complete backtrace.

Comment: **and your code** `app/controllers/application_controller.rb:707` ±10 LOCs and `app/controllers/pictures_controller.rb:17` ±10 LOCs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue, I noticed that some other user had permission on `s3fs-passwd` file inside `/etc` folder. Gave deploy user the access to that file by doing `chown deploy:deploy s3fs-passwd` and the `/public/system` started showing correct file permissions on mounting instead of `?? ?????` and uploads are working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Most obvious solution would be to allow webserver to produce `public/system` directory as it wants to. In `deploy.rb` remove it:

```
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push(
  %w|log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle|
)
```

Now the server should have this directory created by itself on first access with the proper rights. In your current scenario, this directory is being created by deploy script, that is running [I suppose] not as webserver user.

---

If this directory is not empty and you still want to deploy it, just instruct `capistrano` to `chown` it to be owned by webserver user.

As a last resort, one might set the rights to `777` but I strongly insist that it is the worst way to solve the issue.

Comment: Should I setup a new code folder again in the server so that access right issues are not there?

Comment: Please read my answer. The destination directory (`releases/20161230073928`) in this particular case is being created by capistrano, as well as all the subdirs.

Comment: The actual problem is `public/system is mounted to a bucket which is being used by our old code and `www-data` user has access to it. Now I am upgrading the codebase to `ruby 2.1.0` and adding capistrano too. So now I created a new user `deploy` to implement `capistrano`. Now when I mount the bucket, `deploy` user does not have access to it. So I created a group `www-data` and added `deploy` user to it changed the owner and group ownership to `www-data`. This worked in my UAT environment but not in production environment as you can see in the above question.

Comment: **remove `public/system` from a list of `:linked_dirs` in `deploy.rb` file**. What’s the problem with reading my answer in the first place?

Comment: thanks. I am currently doing cap deploy to check if its fixed. I have one doubt as I explained in my last comment, do you think just **removing public/system** from **linked_dirs** would have worked?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131884/discussion-between-sahil-and-mudasobwa).

Comment: Thanks a lot now image upload is working, but during deploy I get this error now: `rm: cannot remove '/var/www/web_cc_cap1/releases/20161230073928/public/uploads/tmp/1483086062-19250-5102/content_2274dec21d76f0e223401d70d1b29340.png` like this I am getting few errors for 4-5 files.

Comment: Try to add `public` (not `public/system`) to the list of linked dirs.

Comment: It again gives this error: `File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /var/www/web_cc_cap1/releases/20161230091410/public/assets`.

Comment: OK, I kinda got it. Finally remove `public` from the list of linked dirs, login to remote and execute `chown -R www-data public`. It should help.

Comment: Does this mean I would have to run this command on each deploy? If yes then should I add this to a new recipe in capistrano at the end of deployment.

Comment: I guess you should run it once, but I am not quite familiar with capistrano to answer this for sure.

Comment: I think so the permissions setup is messed up, as now I get `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/www/web_cc_cap1/shared/public/assets’`.

Comment: I have again deployed my code with `set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle','public/system')` setting and as it was deploy the app started running. I am able to upload images from ckeditor now which gets stored in `public/system/ckeditor` folder. But the images which are stored using this setting in my model.rb file `:url  => "/system/coverimage/:id/:basename.:extension"` are not accessible. I am trying desperately and I am very close to completing the deployment.

Comment: Plus if I try to deploy my code again I get this error `mkdir stdout: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/cc/apps/web_cc_cap1/shared/public/system’: File exists`. And the file permissions on shared/public/system are `d?????????  ? ?  ?       ?            ? system`.

Comment: fixed the issue, I noticed that some other user had permission on `s3fs-passwd` file inside `/etc` folder. Gave deploy user the access to that file and the `/public/system` started showing correct file permissions and uploads are working fine now. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the same error and the reason was that `public/system` was a symlink (I was migrating). I could trick rails into not failing by using a *bind mount* instead of a symlink:

`mount --bind /orig/public/system /your/public/system`

Hope it helps someone.